# calling C++ "int WINAPI _tWinMain" from C#

Tags: c#, c++

I can access a method from a C++ Dll using C# using this method in the C++:

```
extern "C"
{
  __declspec(dllexport) void DisplayHelloFromDLL()
  {
    printf ("Hello from DLL !\n");
  }
}
```

this works great...but the solution I am working with uses this as the entry point:

```
extern "C" int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                                HINSTANCE /*hPrevInstance*/,
                                LPTSTR lpCmdLine,
                                int /*nShowCmd*/)
```

Is there a way I can access this like I have done with the `__declspec` method?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was to call a function created in the C++ using:

```
extern "C"
{
  __declspec(dllexport) void StartAgent()
  {
    printf ("Starting Agent... \n");

    StartServer(true);
    RunMainLoop();
  }
}
```

This is then called in the C# using:

```
[DllImport("myDll.dll")]
public static extern string StartAgent();

StartAgent();
```

Calling this from the C# and into the C++ gets the application running.

Answer (score 4):

That is not a DLL entry point, that is a primary application entry point. You will need to create it as a new process via CreateProcess.

Answer (score 4):

`_tWinMain` is actually a `#define` to either `WinMain` or `wWinMain`. You also need to make sure it's actually exported.

That being said, why would a DLL have a `WinMain` function at all? You should just export a normal function like `DisplayHelloFromDLL`.

[edit]

The project you are trying to reference -- the one with `_tWinMain` -- is an EXE (as @DeadMG says). You should not try to import its functions from C# like you do with DLLs; instead you should launch it with [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx).

Comment: ok, how can I get into this ddl to start it up? I should point out here I have zero experience in using C++